# Isolate Android Contact Provider

Tags: android, contacts, provider

I want to create a Contact Provider so I can populate it from our database and let our business workforce to have all the customer data. That's the "easy" part.

But what I need is to isolate those contacts and avoid them to be cloned disallowing the people to copy/clone them and loosing track of that information.

Is there a way to do that? I haven't found a way to do that and I think the only way is to show the contacts in a custom Contact app. The problem with that solution is that it wouldn't be possible to know who's calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that?

On an Android device, there will be roughly zero lines of code that knows anything about a custom `ContentProvider` that you create. If you do not want to share data from that provider, do not offer any UI to allow people to share data from that provider, and do not export the provider to third-party apps.

> I haven't found a way to do that and I think the only way is to show the contacts in a custom Contact app

You needed to write that anyway. There are ~2 billion Android devices. None of them will have a Contacts-style app that knows anything about some custom `ContentProvider` that you create.

> The problem with that solution is that it wouldn't be possible to know who's calling.

Correct. After all, the devices' call managers do not know anything about your custom `ContentProvider`.

Now, it could be that by "create a Contact Provider", you really meant "**not** create a Contact Provider". In this case, the "it" in "I can populate it from our database and let our business workforce to have all the customer data" might mean the standard Android `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider`. In this case, the Contacts app and in-call screens and everything else that works with contacts will work with your contacts. However, this is a system-supplied `ContentProvider`, exported to third-party apps, with documentation and so on. There are thousands of apps, both pre-installed and available via the Play Store and elsewhere, that can work with `ContactsContract`. You have no means of stopping that, and you have no means of preventing those apps from doing whatever it is that they want with this data.

IOW, you cannot satisfy "I want the Contacts app to have my contacts" and "I do not want the Contacts app to have my contacts" at the same time.